# Will Nexus 7 with Ubuntu run Eclipse and FDT and compile out via OTG USB to another android device?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Very specific question I know, but has anyone tried Eclipse with [FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/) on the Nexus 7 port of Ubuntu?  I see that Eclipse should be armhf (ARM processor compiled), so, any chance the ADB (Android Debug Bridge) packaging works via [OTG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) (on the go) USB to another Android device?

Just thinking if the N7 could be used as a basic dev tool.

Comment: PLease make your question better readable by replacing the many abbreviations - even if the question is very specific, not only specialists should be able to understand it.

Comment: Edited. But to be fair, the acronyms are pretty common and sincerely not wanting to come across rude, but if you don't know them, you probably won't be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to compile adb for arm, which is quite doable.

As for actually using eclipse, I'm not sure how practical that is it's very memory intensive.

However using something like ant, in connection with adb might be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My aim was actually to run the FDT plugin, which is a Flash Air IDE. Idea was to publish out to a connected phone since there was mention that Flash doesn't run on Ubuntu being x86. Memory well probably be the biggest issue. I saw my PC version is currently eating about 550meg ram...

Comment: its really dependant on the FDT plugin as well. if its wholly written in java you are ok, if it has some native component you'll have troubles. baring you'll need a adb compiled for arm, but I'm sure that is achievable.